# Rowspan like structure in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to imitate table rowspan behavior with divs (not with a table)?

Something like this:

```
+---+----+
|   |  B |
| A +----+
|   |  C |
+---+----+
```

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: possible duplicate of [colspan and rowspan in div tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255445/colspan-and-rowspan-in-div-tag)

Comment: Why would you want to? If it looks like a `<table>`, make it a `<table>`. The myth of "omg tables are bad" is from when people realised that using *tables for **layout*** was bad; not that they should be avoided for situations they were ***built for***.

Comment: It looks like it is a table? It has a total of three cells! What sort of tabular data can you express in three cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using css rules display:inline-block may help you too

```
.cell{
    zoom:1;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:-moz-inline-box;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
}
```

then specifying width and height you should be able to do what you want. This is not the best or worst solution just another way to go

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your div structure. For example you can something like that:
http://jsfiddle.net/avall/5ky5b/

Using floated divs and smart use of background can make this effect.